# How can I read system input in Swift easily

Tags: swift, string

I'm beginner in Swift and am having a hard time dealing with Swift String.
It has many differences from other languages I think.

So, can somebody tell me why is this statement incorrect?

I want to read a Line and insert each one Integer to variable `n, l`

in C, like this -> `scanf("%d %d", &n, &l);`

```swift
var n, l : Int?
var read : String = readLine()!
n = Int(read[read.startIndex])
l = read[read.index(read.startIndex, offsetBy : 2)]
```

Comment: To scan, use Scanner. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle input for a cli tool in Swift is probably by using the official [ArgumentParser](https://swift.org/blog/argument-parser/) library.

But a *super naive* implementation would involve something like:

- Read the input
- Split it using spaces
- Try to parse into `Int`s

The following example is of course not something that could be used for anything other than learning...:

```
print("Please input 2 numbers separated by space:")

let read = readLine()

if let inputs = read?.split(separator: " ") // Split using space
        .map(String.init)                   // Convert substring to string
        .compactMap(Int.init),              // Try to convert to Ints (get rid of nils)
        inputs.count > 1 {                  // Ensure that we got at least 2 elements
            let (n, l) = (inputs[0], inputs[1])
            print(n, l)
} else {
    // Handle the case
}
```

Comment: You can merge second map and compactMap to `compactMap { Int($0) }`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Of course. You're right, I first wrote the comments and then the code but I guess less code is better code :P Thanks